# Why java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity. Error after taking picture with camera of my android application?

Tags: android, camera

My android application showing force close error when I am capturing a image at landscape mode and trying to upload at portrait mod. The error like..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CameraSample/testphoto20120717_103942-899201574.jpg typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.freedom.net/com.example.android.photobyintent.PhotoIntentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)

```
public class PhotoIntentActivity extends MenuActivitySpecific {

private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
private ImageView mImageView;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
private Handler imageUploadhandler, databaseHandler;
DBAdapter db;
private Dialog dialog;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private  Uri imageUri1=null;
private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "testphoto";
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
File afile;
private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;


/* Photo album for this application */
private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.album_name);
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocusFlag) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocusFlag);       
    if (hasFocusFlag) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
}

private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp ;
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

    File f = createImageFile();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

    return f;
}

private void setPic() {


    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 
            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 
                                  matrix, true);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotated);

    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        afile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        String abcd=afile.toString();
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(afile);
        imageUri1 = Uri.parse(abcd);
        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(new File(abcd).toString());
        Uri uri3 = Uri.fromFile(new File(abcd));
        Log.i("uri1, uri2, uri3 :", imageUri1+","+uri2+","+uri3+"");
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch(actionCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;          
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}




private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }

}



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameracapturedimage);
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    imageUploadhandler = new Handler();
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);
    //mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    mImageBitmap = null;
    //mVideoUri = null;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
    } else {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
    }

    dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menucapturedimage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.backToHome:
        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        upload();
        return true;
    case R.id.retakePicture:
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhotoIntentActivity.this, Home.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B


    } // switch
}

// Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);

    outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                    ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
    );

}

public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}


public void upload() {
    try {
        boolean check = Utility.isNetworkAvailable(PhotoIntentActivity.this);
        // boolean check1 =isOnline();
        if (check) {



            String newtime = Utility.getdate();
            String accesskey = Utility.MD5_Hash(Constants.email + newtime
                    + "moko");
            Constants.ACCESS_KEY = accesskey;
            Constants.proc_date = newtime;
            imageUploadhandler.postDelayed(runImageUpload, 500);
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoIntentActivity.this, "",
                    "しばらくお待ちください", true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
        } else {

            databaseHandler.postDelayed(runDatabaseImageSave, 500);
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoIntentActivity.this, "",
                    "しばらくお待ちください", true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        dialog.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(this, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private final Runnable runImageUpload = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        Log.i("contentUri1", imageUri1+"");
        ResponseFromServer response = Utility.uploadFileAsImage(afile,
                PhotoIntentActivity.this);

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (response != null) {


            if (response.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "画像を保存しました。",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoIntentActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("エラー")
                    .setMessage("ファイル送信に失敗しました。")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }
                            }).show();
            return;

        }

    }
};

private final Runnable runDatabaseImageSave = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        try {
            InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageUri1);

            byte[] inputData = iStream.toString().getBytes();
            db.open();
            String stringUri = imageUri1.toString();
            String userMail = Constants.email;
            Log.e("Email: ", userMail + "");
            boolean feedback = db.InsertImage(inputData, stringUri,
                    userMail, 1);

            db.close();

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (feedback) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoIntentActivity.this, "画像を保存しました。",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoIntentActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("エラー")
                        .setMessage("ファイル送信に失敗しました。")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                }).show();
                return;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error to upload Image to database: ", e + "");
        }

    }
};



}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are referring to change in orientation,from picture click to picture upload,I think you are not handling configuration changes

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
          android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

Just put following on your manifest file and see whether it works or not

Comment: I don't think the evidence suggests an issue here. He clearly has an NPE in his code.

Comment: Now I am uring android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize and @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   setContentView(R.layout.cameracapturedimage);
 }  But still sometimes showing ForceClose error.\

Comment: I did had an application which was totally on portrait mode,and when the app need to capture image,the phone went to landscape mode.So,I didn't put any  "onSavedInstance" and "onRestoreInstance" as in your code,and captured the data from onActivityResult and put the above on "Manifest file". That's why I posted the above "Manifest" tag.But I don't know the scenario you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

The end of your log message points to the problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. There should be a stack trace following that. Your `Activity` is throwing an exception when it handles the reply `Intent`. I assume the stack trace will show an error in `onActivityResult()` and where the error is.